# How can I declare new array to append tuple array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays and content is tuple . I need to show it table view different sections. However, I would like to put both array in an array. So what is the best way to declare new array to append `devCourses` and `webCourses` array .

```
  var devCourses = [
            ("iOS App","Simon Allardice"),
            ("iOS 9 with swift","Matt Neuburg")]

    var webCourses = [
            ("HTML","James"),
            ("Design","Ray") ]
```

[image]

I need to declare it outside the `viewdidload` and 
append it inside the `viewdidload` .

Answer (score 0):

As Array :

```
var courses:[[(String, String )]]!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    var devCourses = [
        ("iOS App","Simon Allardice"),
        ("iOS 9 with swift","Matt Neuburg")]

    var webCourses = [
        ("HTML","James"),
        ("Design","Ray") ]

    courses = [devCourses , webCourses]
    print(courses)
}
```

As Dictionary: This is better option if you want to show section title in the table section header.

```
var courses:[String:[(String, String )]]! = [:]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let devCourses = [
        ("iOS App","Simon Allardice"),
        ("iOS 9 with swift","Matt Neuburg")]

    let webCourses = [
        ("HTML","James"),
        ("Design","Ray") ]

    courses["devCourses"] = devCourses
    courses["webCourses"] = webCourses
    print(courses)
}
```

Comment: I see no reason for `courses` to be an implicitly unwrapped optional (`!`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use append function for adding new element into your array, but this situation I'll advise you to use classes, if you can use classes, managing your code is more easily for you.